# How to use "chartjs-chart-graph"(force directed graph) in Angular?

Tags: angular, chart.js

I have installed the "chartjs-chart-graph" using the below command:
"npm install --save chart.js chartjs-chart-graph"

*Please see the link: https://github.com/sgratzl/chartjs-chart-graph*

Then in Angular "/app/directedgraph/directedgraph.component.ts", I have imported "chartjs-chart-graph" like shown below:

```
import  'chartjs-chart-graph/build/Chart.Graphs.js';
```

I have pasted the code written in "directedgraph.component.ts"

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Chart} from 'chart.js'; 
import  'chartjs-chart-graph/build/Chart.Graphs.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-directedgraph',
  templateUrl: './directedgraph.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./directedgraph.component.css']
})

export class DirectedgraphComponent implements OnInit {

  directedCanvas:any;
  directedContext:any;
  nodeData:any[];
  edgeData:any[];


 ngOnInit() {
    this.nodeData = [
      {  id: '1',label: 'Node A'},
      {  id: '2',label: 'Node B'},
      {  id: '3',label: 'Node C'},
      {  id: '4',label: 'Node D'},
      {  id: '5',label: 'Node E'},
      {  id: '6',label: 'Node F'}];

      this.edgeData = [
        {id: 'a', source: '1', target: '2'},
        {id: 'b',source: '1',target: '3'},
        {id: 'c',source: '3',target: '4'},
        {id: 'd',source: '3',target: '5'},
        {id: 'e',source: '4',target: '5'},
        {id: 'f',source: '2',target: '6'}
      ];

    this.directedCanvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    this.directedContext = this.directedCanvas.getContext('2d');

      var chart = new Chart(this.directedContext, {
            type: 'forceDirectedGraph',
            data: {
              labels: ['A', 'B', 'C'], // node labels
              datasets: [{
                pointBackgroundColor: 'steelblue',
                pointRadius: 5,
                data: this.nodeData,
                edges:this.edgeData
              }]
            },
            options: {
              simulation: {
                forces: {
                  link: {
                    id: (d) => d.id
                  }
                }
              },
              legend: {
                display: false
              }
            }
          });
  }
}
```

Now coming to the issue:

I am getting errors for edges and simulation property. Please see the errors listed below:

> Type '{ pointBackgroundColor: string; pointRadius: number; data:
>   any[]; edges: any[]; }' is not assignable to type 'ChartDataSets'.
>   Object literal may only specify known properties, and **'edges' does
>   not exist in type 'ChartDataSets'.**
>
> Type '{ responsive: boolean; simulation: { forces: { link: { id: (d:
>   any) => any; }; }; legend: { display: boolean; }; }; }' is not
>   assignable to type 'ChartOptions'.   Object literal may only specify
>   known properties, and **'simulation' does not exist in type
>   'ChartOptions'.**

Finally this is my .html code:

```
 <canvas id="canvas" width="70vw"></canvas>
```

Comment: I recommend https://gojs.net/latest/index.html gojs lib to you it has everything related to graph

Comment: and this demo to how to use it https://github.com/AhmedMahmoud2012/gojs

Comment: Thank you, but we need to work with chart.js. Is there any suggestion to resolve the issue?

Comment: Any solution for force directed graph using chart.js?

Comment: https://github.com/vasturiano/force-graph